# Divi / Wordpress mobile menu 1click issue

Tags: css, wordpress

I have run into a SUPER annoying issue in my mobile menu (https://www.aalborgkarneval.dk). When I click on the menu titles I have to double click on most of the menu titles for it to expand (+ works every time). Next issue is that I also have to press the sub titles multiple times also for it to go the the page.

For some reason this does not apply to the INFO tab, why I do not know.

-Testet on iOS.

Anyone can help??

Answer (score 0):

can you give a try for the below:

**Remove hover related CSS for menu items and check because in IOS 1st click is assumed as hover and second click is referred as actual click**

Comment: Great input, this could easily be the case since first time I click it highlights the hover cover. (it doesn't do it on the INFO tab though, which is strange?). I haven't included external hover CSS, I only used the wordpress/divi theme options. Do you know if I can look into something there?

Comment: But I am able to see a bit of hover CSS being used on those menu items. So please set the hover of that menu items to UNSET

Comment: As mentioned it is not something I have applied. It is something within the Divi Theme. I do not know how to disable it unfortunately.

Comment: Ok so for menu items can you add this css  `pointer-events: none;`